# How to search a string specifically in middle of another string

Tags: php, sql, string, sql-like, relevance

Searching substring in all columns of the table.Result to be displayed in following order:
1.first results starting with substring.
2.Then results in which substring **in middle and not at last**.
3.Then results in which substring is at last.
The problem arises when searching for substring in **middle and not at last** because like %substring% will also contain %substring which is actually **at last**.So the order is not preserved.

```
foreach($results as $r){
$append1 ="select * from ".$tablename." WHERE ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." like'".$substring."%'union ";
$query1 = $query1.$append1;
}  
foreach($results as $r){
$append2 ="select * from ".$tablename." WHERE ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." like'%".$substring."%'union";
$query2 = $query2.$append2;
}
foreach($results as $r){
$append3 ="select * from ".$tablename." WHERE ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." like'%".$substring."'union";
$query3 = $query3.$append3;
}
$query4=$query1.$query2.$query3;
$query4 = substr($query4, 0, -5);
```

Comment: depending on what you are really trying to do you might be better off with full text searches with a score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator uses two wildcard characters.  You already know about `%`, but there's also `_` (which basically means "exactly one of any character").

So you can do the second query like

```
$append2 ="SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE {$r['COLUMN_NAME']} LIKE '_%{$substring}%_' union";
```

and it should only match where there's at least one character before `$substring` and one after.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add in an extra bit to the WHERE clause to exclude where the string is at the end.

```
$append2 ="select * from ".$tablename." WHERE ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." like '%".$substring."%' AND ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." NOT like '%".$substring."' union";
```

As an aside, mysql_* functions are deprecated, and you should really look into mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regular expressions](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Regular_Expression_Searches) instead.  For example:

```
 $append1 ="select * from ".$tablename." WHERE ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." REGEXP '".$substring."$' union ";  // match ending

 $append1 ="select * from ".$tablename." WHERE ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." REGEXP '[[:print:]]".$substring."[[:print:]]' union ";  // match middle

 $append1 ="select * from ".$tablename." WHERE ".$r['COLUMN_NAME']." REGEXP '^".$substring."' union ";  // match beginning
```